# How to plot classes in R?

Tags: r

Good afternoon :

My question is very simple but i failed to find a right solution.

Suppose that i have an array of 3 columns :

- Column 1 : X as axis position ( numerical values )
- Column 2 : Y as axis position ( numerical values )
- Column 4 : identification of object ( ex : vector_1 , vector_2 , etc. )
- Column 4 : a label of classe such as "Class_A" , "Class_B" ,"Class_C".

> x <- data.frame("x" = 1:3, "Y" = c(4,6,7), "object" = c("John","Dora"
>   , "Peter") , "Class"=("Class_A" , "Class_B" ,"Class_C" ) )

How can i plot this in R ?

I want that each class have a different color / shape. X & Y are 2d positions.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: `plot(x[,1:2], pch=15+as.numeric(x$Class), col=x$Class)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#R version 3.3.2 
x <- data.frame("x" = 1:3 , "Y" = c(4,6,7) , "object" = c("John","Dora" , "Peter") , "Class"=c("Class_A" , "Class_B" ,"Class_C" ) )
z=x

plot(x[,1:2], pch=15+as.numeric(x$Class), col=x$Class) 
text(x=z$"x", y=z$"Y",labels=x$"object")
```